# How to mount a xfs volume to centOS 7 ec2 instance /home directory

Tags: centos, mount, home, amazon-ec2, xfs

I created `t2.medium` instance and attached `ebs` volume to the instance

Here are some useful information.

`sudo pvs`

```
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
/dev/xvdb1 vg_home lvm2 a--  <200.00g    0
```

`sudo vgs`

```
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
vg_home   1   1   0 wz--n- <200.00g    0
```

`sudo lvs`

```
 LV      VG      Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_home vg_home -wi-a----- <200.00g
```

`lsblk`

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda                202:0    0   50G  0 disk
└─xvda1             202:1    0   50G  0 part /
xvdb                202:16   0  200G  0 disk
└─xvdb1             202:17   0  200G  0 part
  └─vg_home-lv_home 253:0    0  200G  0 lvm
```

`lsblk -lf`

```
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
xvda
xvda1           xfs               0356e691-d6fb-4f8b-a905-4230dbe62a32   /
xvdb
xvdb1           LVM2_member       qSmSpW-MRuF-WrUE-jJL8-N182-xOgA-57kdkB
vg_home-lv_home xfs               b4fadb7e-714c-4cdd-a5dd-43df5ef19b84
```

So I need to mount `vg_home-lv_home` to `/home` directory.

I can mount this volume by running `sudo mount /dev/vg_home/lv_home /home`

Then its mounted. After that, I terminated my ssh session and try to ssh again.
`ssh -i <key> centos@<ec2_public_ip>`. I can't ssh into ec2 instance, error is `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

It makes sense, because I mounted `/dev/vg_home/lv_home` to `/home`.
and `.ssh` folder has gone from `/home`

Then I restarted the ec2 instance and I can ssh it again.

So my question is how can I mount `xfs` volume to `/home` directory?

I created a mountpoint `/mnt/home` and copied `/home` then unmounted from `mnt/home` and mounted to `/home`. Then I can't connected to ec2 instance at all (with restart).

So what is the best practice/method to mount a volume to ec2 instance `/home` directory?

-Thank you

Comment: You need to make sure you use `cp -a` to preserve permissions. You also likely need to temporary disable SELinux and set relabel the files in the new volume.

Comment: hey @jordanm, I'm a newbie to Linux. could you please give me a reference (link/tutorial), please? Thank you

Comment: I just checked and `cp -a` alone should cover both permissions and SELinux context labels.

Answer (score 1):

- Make temp directory to mount - `sudo mkdir -p /srv/home`
- Mount - `sudo mount /dev/vg_home/lv_home /srv/home`
- Copy file from home to temp directory - `sudo cp -aR /home/* /srv/home/`
- Check the difference between two directories - `diff -r /home /srv/home`
- Afterwards delete all the old content on the `/home` as follow - `rm -rf /home/*`
- Umount from tempdir - `sudo umount /srv/home`
- Mount to `/home` - `sudo mount /dev/vg_home/lv_home /home`
- Delete temp mounted directory - sudo rm -r /srv/home/
- edit `/etc/fstab` file - `/dev/mapper/vg_home-lv_home /home   xfs defaults    0   2`